# Custom background for UIActionSheet in a UIPopoverController on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet

What I'm basically doing is presenting a `UIActionSheet` using showFromBarButtonItem from a `UIBarButtonItem` in a `UINavigationBar` in an iPad app. What this does is present the `UIActionSheet` in a `popover`, which is what I wanted.

What I would like to do is change the background color of said popover from the default blue to one of my own. Is there a simple app store safe way to accomplish this short of rolling my own custom `UIActionSheet` in a popover solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, because you don't get official access to any parts of the underlying UIPopoverController or its content view controller, let alone the view. On the other hand, as you imply, constructing your own view controller and view is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0):

It would be quite easy to create your own view with behavior similar to UIActionSheet

Here's an example: http://iosdevtricks.blogspot.com/2013/04/ipad-style-action-sheet-for-iphone.html

Comment: While you're correct that it is fairly easy to do. At the link you point to, the end result looks like a UIAlerView, not a UIActionSheet!

Comment: it has the same behavior as action sheet on iPad (clicking outside of it will dismiss action sheet), and since graphics is custom anyway - you can achieve any look you want by replacing background and button images